# How best to graphically represent an r-square effect-size measure?

Tags: correlation

It is easy to graph effect size (r) for a correlation in the form of a scatterplot.

However, how do I graph the variance (r-squared)? Any thoughts on best practice?

Comment: I've slightly altered the meaning of your original title. Please, check that it does indeed correspond to what you initially meant.

Comment: A description of the dataset or of your purpose would help.  After all, both $r$ and $r^2$ are just numbers: you might just as well report them.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15168/graphing-effect-size-for-coefficient-of-determination

Comment: Finally, how does this question differ from your previous one, as pointed out by @Thomas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short Answer

- If you have bivariate data, then a scatterplot suggests as much about $r$ as it does $r^2$.

#### Longer Answer

- The points on a scatterplot can be extracted to yield $r$ or $r^2$.
- Graphs are commonly used instead of summary statsitics or raw data in order to take advantage of the power of the human visual-perceptual system. As such, when we look at a scatterplot we can get a sense of the direction, form, and degree of the relationship between two numeric variables.
- The degree of linear relationship in the data from a scatterplot is captured in $r$ and $r^2$. $r$ is directional and $r^2$ is not. They also quantify the degree of relationship in different ways.
- In some sense  $r$ and $r^2$ are not directly communicated by the scatterplot. Rather you can train your intuition over time to estimate the $r$ or $r^2$ for a given scatterplot. Alternatively, the scatterplot can be seen as a tool to train your intuition of the meaning of $r$ and $r^2$. If you need practice, check out [this applet](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~lane/stat_sim/reg_by_eye/).
- If you are wanting to combine the plot with the summary statistic, you can always add $r$ or $r^2$ to the plot. I find this useful for slide presentations. There are also functions like `pairs.panels` in the `psych` package in R which will print a scatterplot matrix with scatterplots in the lower triangle of cells and the value of the correlation in the upper triangle of cells. See [here](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=psych%3apairs.panels) for an example.

Comment: Thanks. I am just confused. If r is 0.5, than r squared is 25%. How does the scatterplot show both values?

Comment: @AdheshJosh I've elaborated on my original answer. I hope it helps.